# Domain of sender address"zzz" does not resolve userid

Tags: sendmail

Getting error while sending mail :

Domain of sender address  "abc@xyz.com" does not resolve userid

Though i am able to send email to many other external/internal domains but few domain not accepting this .

Is this related to A records that recipient is checking and not accepting these emails .

Note : We changed the sender FROM address in sendmail to some other name and that might not have "A record"

Comment: Ugh, SendMail configs... Try [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).